# How to read information from a piecewise function?

Tags: list-manipulation, piecewise

I defined a periodic piece wise function `y[x_]` with some discrete steps with `Piecewise` command and two lists `xv` and `yv`, which are the end points and values of the pieces, respectively. `y[x_]` is shown below.

[image: y[x_]]

Then I do a shifted and linearly combined version from `y[x_]`, e.g., `ys = y[x] - 1/2 y[x - 120] - 1/2 y[x + 120]`. `ys[x_]` is shown below.

[image: ys[x_]]

My question is, how to "read" from the synthesized function `ys` the information of the end points and values of all pieces? For the example given, I would like two lists to be produced in the form of `xsv = {-180, -150, -90, -30, 30, 90, 150, 180}` and `ysv = {-2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2}`.

The code for this process is

```
xv = {-180, -90, 90, 180};
yv = {-1, 1, -1};
y[x_] := Piecewise[Table[{yv[[i]], xv[[i]] < Mod[x, 360, -180] < xv[[i + 1]]}, {i, Length[yv]}]];
Plot[y[x], {x, -180, 180}, Exclusions -> None]
ys = y[x] - 1/2 y[x - 120] - 1/2 y[x + 120];
Plot[ys, {x, -180, 180}, Exclusions -> None]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pw[x_] = PiecewiseExpand[ys, -180 < x < 180]
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  -2 & x>150\lor x<-150 \\
>  -\frac{3}{2} & x=-150\lor x=150 \\
>  -1 & -150<x<-90\lor 90<x<150 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} & x=-60\lor x=60 \\
>  1 & -90<x<-60\lor -60<x<-30\lor 30<x<60\lor 60<x<90 \\
>  \frac{3}{2} & x=-30\lor x=30 \\
>  2 & -30<x<30
> \end{cases}$$

Because the function is piecewise constant, we may apply the following trick to extract the discontinuities:

```
xsv = Join[{-180}, Union@Cases[D[pw[x], x][[1, 1, 2]], _?NumericQ, ∞], {180}]
ysv = Map[pw, MovingAverage[xsv, 2]]
```

> {-180, -150, -90, -60, -30, 30, 60, 90, 150, 180}
>
> {-2, -1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, -1, -2}

Comment: I would like two lists to be produced in the form of xsv = {-180, -150, -90, -30, 30, 90, 150, 180} and ysv = {-2, -1, 1, 2, 1, -1, -2}. The function values at the transition points are also desired to be ignored.